# How do characters get translated to bytes written to text files?

Tags: c, text, output

In the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    putchar ( '^' ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

I expect an "^" to appear in the console. But how is it that the compiler knows which pattern of bits to send to the file connected to `stdout`? It seems unlikely that the compiler knows which terminal or terminal emulator I will run the program with. And there are also code pages, fonts, and other runtime stuff that the compiler does not know at compile time.

From the discussion and answers so far, it appears to be the responsibility of the compiler user together with the compiler to specify and implement the execution character set. However, the compiler's implementation may be to defer to "the system’s iconv library routine" ([gcc invocation `-fexec-charset`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html)). It would then be the user's (and/or IT guru's) responsibility to execute the program using a compatible terminal, terminal settings (encoding settings), and font. Am I missing anything? Perhaps a complete answer is possible only by specifying compilers, terminals, etc.

Comment: Compiler does not need to know about the underlying terminal. Its the _C Standard Library_ which takes care of I/O processing. Read about and make yourself familiar with [C Standard Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library).

Comment: You might benefit from https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases

Comment: `putchar('^')` will send the pattern of bits that correspond to the character `^`. That's most probably 01011110 (the ASCII code of `^`). It doesn't care about terminals, code pages, fonts, or any such thing. If you use a wrong font, a wrong code page, or a wrong terminal emulator, you just won't see expected output. This doesn't happen much with '^' because ASCII is incorporated in every code page and most fonts you are likely to use. But it does happen a lot with characters beyond ASCII. Stackoverflow is full of questions about it.

Comment: ... (cont's) The above is a good enough approximation for most purposes. In reality, there is an additional translation step that may happen in the standard library. The translation is driven by the [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale). Your compiler may use ASCII, your terminal may use EBCDIC, and if the locale is set up correctly, you will still see `^` on the terminal because the standard library knows how to translate between the two.

Comment: @DavidJones Re: "translation_phases"---Indeed, Phase 5 converts from the source character set to the execution character set. It is apparently the complier's responsibility to perform this, perhaps constrained by the compiler-user's selection of an option to specify the execution character set.

Comment: re: "Compiler does not need to know about the underlying terminal".  What "underlying terminal"?  The complier doesn't need or care or want to know if there is a terminal, and very frequently there is none.

Answer (score 2):

The standard function `putchar` copies a byte (passed as an `int` value and converted to `unsigned char` internally) to the standard output stream `stdout`, which is by default line buffered if attached to a terminal.

It is common for `putchar` to be implemented as a macro defined in `<stdio.h>`, but there should also be a function `putchar` defined in `<stdio.h>` and you can ensure the function is called an not the macro by writing: `(putchar)('^')`.

Whether implemented as a macro of a function, the behavior is exactly the same: the byte is written to the buffer attached to the `FILE` structure `stdout` points to, and depending on the state of this `FILE`, the buffer may be flushed to the system immediately or later, possibly delayed until the program exits by returning from `main` or calling the `exit` function.

The byte value for `'^'` (which is a character constant with type `int` in C) depends on the *execution character set*.  On almost all current systems, the character `^` is encoded in ASCII as the byte value 94 (octal `0136`, hex `0x5e`). The character in the source file is stored in the *source character set* which is also ASCII or a superset on most current systems.  Some older IBM mainframes still use EBCDIC which encodes `'^'` as the value `176` (`0xB0`), but you are unlikely to have to write C code for these.

This byte value may be translated by the C library stream handling functions to account for system specific behaviors if the stream is open in text mode.  No such translation occurs for streams open in binary mode (as with `fopen(filename, "wb")`). The translation could be to convert `'\n'` as a 2 byte sequence CR LF or convert characters between the execution character set and some system specific locale selected for the current process and stream.  No such translations are performed on Unix systems, but very intricate conversions can be selected on legacy systems.

After this possible conversion, the byte(s) are transferred to the system handle attached to `stdout`, which could be a disk file, a pipe, a character device such as serial line or a terminal emulator...

The terminal emulator adds its own layer of processing to display certain byte values as characters in the current font and color combinations or interpret them as commands to move the cursor (such as CR, LF, TAB, BS, VT) or as part of longer sequences to perform all sorts of functions (these are known as escape sequences as they usually start with the ESC byte 27 or 0x1B).

The terminal may also interpret certain sequences of bytes as composing non-ASCII characters from a much larger character set. An example of this is the UTF-8 standard that represents Unicode code points with sequences of 2 to 4 bytes and encode more than 100000 glyphs. The terminal may then also handle complex character compositions such as combining accents and diacritic marks and handling bidirectional text. The terminal applications are quite complex to support both legacy behaviors dating back 60 years and modern usage evolutions such as emoticons.

Answer (score 1):

The function `putchar()` is part of the C standard library. The source code of this library is compiled by a compiler/assembler that is compatible with the host platform.

On Windows, you use a C compiler compatible with Windows and on Linux, you use one that is compatible with Linux, etc. So the function `putchar()` works as intended on both platforms.

Comment: I've added another paragraph to the question. I hope that makes it clear why I have not (yet) chosen this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`putchar()` is a C standard library function whose job is to write a character, passed as an argument, to `stdout`. Its declaration exists in C Standard Library header file - `<stdio.h>`. When you compile your program, the compiler finds the declaration in the header file and the linker links the program with the definition of the `putchar()` function that it finds in C Standard Library.

The implementation of `putchar()` may vary based on the underlying OS/platform but the end result will be same on all OS's/platforms. That means, on a platform, `putchar()` knows how to write a character to `stdout`. Compiler has nothing to do with implementation of `putchar()`.

Comment: I've added another paragraph to the question. I hope that makes it clear why I have not (yet) chosen this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To the question

> How do characters get translated to bytes written to text files? [In particular], how is it that the compiler knows which pattern of bits to send to the file connected to stdout?

Characters of the *source character set* are are translated to characters of the *execution character set* by the compiler and its dependencies (such as [iconv](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)). The source and executuon character sets and their encodings are implementation-defined (with some constraints, e.g., that certain characters be represented). Some compilers allow the compiler user to specify the character sets and encodings. In particular, the translation process is ignorant of terminals, terminal settings, and fonts.